# Finding the largest mirror image of a subset/set of integers present in an array of integers

Tags: java, programming-challenge, palindrome

The problem I am talking about is [this](http://codingbat.com/prob/p196409):

> We'll say that a "mirror" section in an array is a group of contiguous
>   elements such that somewhere in the array, the same group appears in
>   reverse order. For example, the largest mirror section in {1, 2, 3, 8,
>   9, 3, 2, 1} is length 3 (the {1, 2, 3} part). Return the size of the
>   largest mirror section found in the given array.
>
> - `maxMirror({1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1})` → `3`
> - `maxMirror({1, 2, 1, 4})` → `3`
> - `maxMirror({7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1})` → `2`

**Conditions for solving:**

1. No other helper methods.
2. Do not use `Java.util.Arrays.copyOf` or any other utility under `Arrays`
3. Do not use collections.

The solution I got was a little messy, and any cleaner solutions are welcome.

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
  final int len=nums.length;
  if(len==0)
  return 0;
  int maxCount=1;
  boolean flag=false;

  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
     int tempCount=1;
     int count=i;
     flag=false;

     for(int j=len-1;j>=0&&(count<len);j--)
     {
        if((nums[count]==nums[j])&&!(flag))
        {
          flag=true;
          count++;
          continue;
        }
        if((nums[count]==nums[j])&&(flag))
        {
          tempCount++;
          count++;
          maxCount=(tempCount>maxCount)?tempCount:maxCount;
         continue;
        }
        if(!(nums[i]==nums[j])&&(flag))
        {
          flag=false;
          count=i;
          tempCount=1;
          continue;
        }
        if((j==count)||(j-count)==1)
        {
          flag=false;
          break;
          }

      }
  }    
      return maxCount;    

}
```

Comment: As your code has already been reviewed, I would just like to propose another solution: to find the longest common "substring" of the array and its reversal. Finding this by dynamic programming can be done in \$O(n^2)\$ time and \$O(n)\$ space.

Comment: dynamic programming?

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring/

Comment: @Anirudh - in case you were wondering, I have deleted my answer. My original mis-reading of the specification meant I made assumptions which were unnecessary, and lead to code that scaled worse than necessary.

Comment: @rolfl You didn't need to delete it still as it was working for all the cases. Request you to undelete so that I can have a look again.

Comment: @mjolka OP's answer performs in \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ time and \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ space (ignoring the space needed for the problem input). DP is overkill here.

Comment: @EmilyL. OP's algorithm is incorrect, as Josay pointed out. [The DP solution](http://ideone.com/GfRAIl) is short and not what I would call overkill.

Comment: @mjolka fixed the code to work for the case pointed by Josay

Comment: You are not supposed to edit the code if your question as it kind of invalidates all reviews done so far. If you want to go one step further, you should post a new question (and precise that it is a follow up of this question).

Comment: It was just a trivial change..the flag wasn't getting set to false afresh in the outer loop. Nothing to that degree has been changed which would invalidate any review here.

Comment: @mojka My comment stands, as the fault was only a minor bug not a faulty method in it self. OP's method is of the right time complexity and better memory performance than the DP solution. Although it could use a run-over by the old sweeping brush.

Comment: @EmilyL. OP's revised code gives a wrong answer (2) for the input [1, 2, 1, 1]. I'm not ruling out a \$O(n^2)\$-time, \$O(1)\$-space algorithm, but as it stands, this solution is wrong.

Comment: @mjolka as I made that minor fix I had to just set the flag to false to outer loop which actually needed to remove the last if statement...and the code is working in most cases maybe all..the code is far from being drastically changed but it should be correct now. Thanks for pointing out the errors...I will post the code as another answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Readibility**

Whitespaces are free and make things easier to read. Also, you do not need that many parenthesis.

Also, indentation seems a bit weird. After fixing this, here is what I have :

```
public class MaxMirror {

    public static int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
        final int len = nums.length;
        if (len == 0)
            return 0;
        int maxCount = 1;
        boolean flag = false;

        for (int i = 0; i<len; i++)
        {
            int tempCount = 1;
            int count = i;

            for (int j = len-1; j>= 0 && (count<len); j--)
            {
                if (nums[count] == nums[j] && !flag)
                {
                    flag = true;
                    count++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (nums[count] == nums[j] && flag)
                {
                    tempCount++;
                    count++;
                    maxCount = (tempCount>maxCount)?tempCount:maxCount;
                    continue;
                }
                if (nums[i] != nums[j] && flag)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    count = i;
                    tempCount = 1;
                    continue;
                }
                if (j == count || (j-count)==1)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }    
        return maxCount;    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
        int[] num = {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1};
        System.out.println(maxMirror(num));
        int[] num2 = {1, 2, 1, 4};
        System.out.println(maxMirror(num2));
        int[] num3 = {7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1};
        System.out.println(maxMirror(num3));
    }
}
```

**Re-writting the logic**

Instead of using `continue`, you could just use `else` between your conditions.

Also, if you have to consider `A && B` and then `A && !B`, you should probably consider `A` and then, as a subcase, the validity of `B`.

Then, you can remove common code from the `then` block and the `else` block.

You can use `max` instead of checking which value is bigger.

You could move your check `count < len` to the only place where count could become bigger than len.

You can rewrite `(j-count)==1` to make it look like the previous expression : `j == (count+1)` seems slightly better.

This being done, your code looks like :

```
public static int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
    final int len = nums.length;
    if (len == 0)
        return 0;
    int maxCount = 1;
    boolean flag = false;

    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++)
    {
        int tempCount = 1;
        int count = i;

        for (int j = len-1; j>= 0; j--)
        {
            if (nums[count] == nums[j])
            {
                if (flag)
                {
                    tempCount++;
                    maxCount = Math.max(tempCount, maxCount);
                }
                flag = true;
                count++;
                if (count>=len)
                    break;
            }
            else if (nums[i] != nums[j] && flag)
            {
                flag = false;
                count = i;
                tempCount = 1;
            }
            else if (j == count || j == (count+1))
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }    
    return maxCount;    
}
```

**Algorithm**

Your algorithm seems to be working. However, I find it hard to understand. I guess a bit of documentation would be useful.

**Edit : bug found ?**

On `int[] num5 = {7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7};`, the function returns 6 and I do not see why.

**Edit 2**

*I originally posted this as a different answer because it is not related to the beginning of this message in any way but this doesn't seem to be much appreciated. As it can be relevant to you, I'm posting this here.*

As your code doesn't really work and I got quite interested by this problem : I took [mjolka](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/44723/mjolka)'s precious comments into account.

Re-adapting code from [the link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring/) in his comment, here what I got :

```
public class MirrorString {
    /* Returns length of longest common substring of X and Y */
    public static int LCSubStr(int[] X /* WAS , int[] Y*/)
    {
        int m = X.length;
        int n = m; // WAS int n = Y.length;

        // Create a table to store lengths of longest common suffixes of
        // substrings.   Notethat LCSuff[i][j] contains length of longest
        // common suffix of X and Y. The first row and
        // first column entries have no logical meaning, they are used only
        // for simplicity of program
        int[][] LCSuff = new int[m+1][n+1];
        int result = 0;  // To store length of the longest common substring

        /* Following steps build LCSuff[m+1][n+1] in bottom up fashion. */
        for (int i=0; i<=m; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<=n; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                    LCSuff[i][j] = 0;
                else if (X[i-1] == X[n-j]) // WAS else if (X[i-1] == Y[j-1])
                {
                    LCSuff[i][j] = LCSuff[i-1][j-1] + 1;
                    result = Math.max(result, LCSuff[i][j]);
                }
                else LCSuff[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
        System.out.println(LCSubStr(new int[] {7, 7, 7, 5, 6, 7, 7})); // 3
        System.out.println(LCSubStr(new int[] {7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7})); // 5
        System.out.println(LCSubStr(new int[] {})); // 0
        System.out.println(LCSubStr(new int[] {1})); // 1
        System.out.println(LCSubStr(new int[] {1, 1})); // 2
        System.out.println(LCSubStr(new int[] {1, 1, 1})); // 3
        System.out.println(LCSubStr(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 2, 1})); // 5
        System.out.println(LCSubStr(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1})); // 3
        System.out.println(LCSubStr(new int[] {1, 2, 1, 4})); // 3
        System.out.println(LCSubStr(new int[] {7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1})); // 2
    }
}
```

I have adapted the code a bit. Then, the only places where the algorithm has been changed are marked with `WAS` :

- only one argument is required now
- instead of accessing the `j-1`th element from J, we access the `n-j`th element from X (simulating a backward traversal).

Please note that things could be done in an even more efficient way using a different data structure as per [the wikipedia page about Longest Common Substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Comment: Thanks for such a nice review, btw is using 'continue' performance wise bad as compared to if else?

Comment: Not quite sure. It should be roughly the same (the generated bytecode might be exactly the same after compilation). In any case, for that kind of problem, you should go for algorithm optimisation and not micro-optimisation. Readibility matters too.

Comment: Yeah in the case you mentioned it should return 4 I think.

Comment: Actually 5? For `7,7,6,7,7`

Comment: yes..5 should be the max length of mirror

Comment: Bug related to case {7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7} fixed now returning 5 instead of 6